# Getting this error while trying to build a simple project using gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-sass

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

I've tried reinstalling node-sass several times to no avail. What should I try next?

I'm on OS X Yosemite and running node v0.10.24 with node-sass 2.0.1.

Comment: What process did you follow for installing node-sass? Have you tried the following?

https://gist.github.com/am11/e5de3c49c219f0811e1d#comment-1386582

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember. It was quite a while ago.

Comment: Try updating node to v0.10.36

Comment: Note that globally installed modules are not available when the program expects a library to be installed locally, within the *node_modules* folder. So perhaps you need to change how you install it.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've just run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for anyone else suddenly getting this issue. I ran: `npm rebuild node-sass` and it completely cured the problem for me.